# Three histograms, three different colours, one figure: matlab

Tags: matlab, histogram

I'm trying to plot the frequencies of different colour pixels in an image. I can draw three separate histograms on three separate figures, but I'd like to draw them all on the same figure, with red for red, green for green etc. From what I can tell from answers on this and other sites, the following should work, but it doesn't, only the second appears. What am I doing wrong?

```
hold on;

x = 0:1:255;
figure ('name', 'red') ;
red = (newImg(:,:,1));
r = red(:)';
r = cast(r,'double');
[graph1,graph2] = hist (r,x);
bar(graph2,graph1, 'FaceColor', 'r','EdgeColor','r')
alpha(0.3);

green = (newImg(:,:,2));
g = green(:)';
g = cast(g,'double');
[graph1,graph2] = hist (g,x);
bar(graph2,graph1, 'FaceColor', 'b','EdgeColor','b')

hold off;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can plot all histograms (RGB channels) in a simpler way, for example:

```
hist(reshape(newImg,[],3),x);
colormap([1 0 0 ; 0 1 0; 0 0 1]); %RGB
```

Here I reshape `newImg` to be a Nx3 matrix, equivalent to the `[r; g ;b]` that you created. Then a single `hist` can process them, and using a custom color map, draws each channel with the correct color it represents.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some nice explanations on how to superpose several histograms with transparency, I think it will help you:
http://desk.stinkpot.org:8080/tricks/index.php/2006/07/how-to-make-a-transparent-histogram-in-matlab/

```
figure;
hist(data1,20);
h = findobj(gca,’Type’,'patch’);
set(h,’FaceColor’,'r’,'EdgeColor’,'w’,'facealpha’,0.75);
hold on
hist(data2,20);
h = findobj(gca,’Type’,'patch’);
set(h,’facealpha’,0.75);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, the 'hold on' needs to come after the first graph is drawn; I assumed it was a toggle - you switch 'hold on' and it keeps holding til you turn it off, apparently not...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new figure (and/or axes) before calling `hold on`, since the hold-state applies on a per-axes basis, and the command `hold on` applies to the current axes. Modify the `NextPlot` property of axes if you want to control the hold state more precisely.

Also, to plot multiple histograms, [distributionPlot](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23661-violin-plots-for-plotting-multiple-distributions-distributionplot-m) from the File Exchange can be useful; in your case, example #7.